# Categories - sub categories traversal algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am looking for good way to traverse a list of categories to create an hierarchy. The present algorithm I am using will not be able to take deep nesting into consideration.

I have a list of all categories (including parent and their all sub-categories), category class is like below:

```
class Category{
     private int id;
     private int parentCategoryId;
     private String name;

     /*Getter Setters*/
}
```

Here the `parentCategoryId` stores the `id` of its parent, root categories will be having `parentCategoryId = 0` and their could be many root categories. Current condition requires me to extend the nesting to atleast 5-6 levels deep, and my current algo fails over that.

What could be a good way to arrange them in such an order that I can easily iterate over them in my view to build something like this:

```
-Root1
--Root1Sub1
--Root1Sub2
---Root1Sub2SubSub1
---Root1Sub2SubSub2
-Root2
--Root2Sub1
```

Comment: post your current algorithm so we can extend it

Comment: It requires recursive algorithm. what is your current one ?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you are looking for is called [Depth-first search, or DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (you can also compare it to [Breadth-first search, BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)).

As written in Wikipedia:

> Depth-first search (DFS) is an algorithm for traversing or searching tree or graph data structures. One starts at the root (selecting some arbitrary node as the root in the case of a graph) and explores as far as possible along each branch before [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

In order to use it efficiently, your class needs to have a list of references to child categories (parent IDs is not important, but you should have actual references, not IDs, of the child categories).

The algorithm (using an explicit stack) is then something like:

```
static void dfs(Category root) {

    Stack stack = new Stack();

    // start by pushing the root node to the stack
    stack.push(root);

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {

        Category node = (Category)stack.pop();

        // do something with this node
        // e.g. System.out.print(node.name);

        // push children to the stack
        stack.addAll(node.children);
    }
}
```

Recursive solution is even simpler:

```
static void recursiveDfs(Category node) {

    // do something with this node
    // e.g. System.out.print(node.name);

    // recursively process all children
    Iterator children = node.children.iterator();
    while (children.hasNext())
        recursiveDfs((Category)children.next());
}
```